# reCAPTCHA fails on one domain - same code (except key) passes on other domain

Tags: php, server, http-post, php-extension, recaptcha

I have two sites
Both of them have a reCAPTCHA 2.0 from google
I have implemented the exact same code on both domains (except for the keys)

To troubleshoot, I have asked the server to show me php-version and extensions:
[Working reCaptcha](http://www.mrm.dk/StackOverflow/success.txt)
[Failing reCaptcha](http://www.mrm.dk/StackOverflow/error.txt)

I have no idea why it fails on the one domain and not at the other.
Both reCaptchas have just been created and are both version 2.0

The basic code for both is:

**Client side:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da-DK">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Recaptcha test</title>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=da'></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>reCAPTCHA</h1>
<form action="responce.php" method="post">

    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Mail: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--My-Site-Key--"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server side:**

```
$sender_name=stripslashes($_POST["name"]);
$sender_email=stripslashes($_POST["email"]);

$secret="--My-Server-Key--";
$response=$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
$success="isFalse";
}
else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
$success="isTrue";
}

echo $success . "<br>";
echo 'php version => '. phpversion() . '<br>';
foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $i => $ext) {
echo $ext .' => '. phpversion($ext). '<br/>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked if the $_POST is not empty?

Comment: Google responce is empty on the one site - but not on the other...

Comment: Google response is empty, but how about the url you're sending to it, it has the $_POST data you intent to post?

Comment: when I ask both to echo the info name and email is received correct. Echoing the $response gives nothing